# Unique ID from combination of all columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm trying to generate a unique ID for the rows of a dataframe based on each column. The columns are a mix of continuous, strings and logical. The intent is that different sort orders would generate the same id. In the reprex below the id's are different, I'd like for them to remain the same:

```
## Two dataframes: same data, different sorting   
df_1 <-structure(list(v1 = c("A", "A", "B"), v2 = c(2, 2, 2), v3 = c(5, 5, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df_2 <- df_1[order(df_1$v3) , ]

## Generate IDs   
df_1$id <- rownames(df_1)
df_2$id <- rownames(df_2)
```

I'm sure this has been dealt with before, but I must not be using the correct terminology.

Comment: I don't follow exactly what you're after; an example on a small set of data would go a long way towards clarifying

Comment: Try `apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=","))`

Comment: Using "continuous" values as part of a per-row-unique hash is perhaps problematic (but certainly not impossible), partly due to the nature of floating point: there is no such thing as `2.0`, it is `2.00000000...`, so it is feasible that the *representation* of two distinct numbers would appear the same (c.f. `2+c(0,1e-8)`). And while I think @akrun's suggestion of `paste` might be appropriate, perhaps your original problem is best handled by assigning an integer to each row, ala `seq_len(nrow(x))`.

Comment: I agree with MichaelChirico though that to get more detailed help, it would help to see a representative (either programmatically with `data.frame(...)` or with `dput(head(x))`). In so doing, please be careful to provide combinations of rows that *should* match, and rows that *should not* match despite seeming very close.

Comment: Added reprex to illustrate what I'm seeking